# how to change the way of GET variables work in php

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I dont like something like this: `example.com/?id=2222`. How to change it into `example.com/2222`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to look into [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

From the documentation: This module uses a rule-based rewriting engine (based on a regular-expression parser) to rewrite requested URLs on the fly.

So the url can look like example.com/2222 for the user, but then translated into example.com/?id=2222 on the server.

Comment: Note that this particular method assumes the Apache webserver is being used.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure `mod_rewrite` is enabled, and you'll need a few lines in an .htaccess file, similar to:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

You can get more information (with lots of examples) [here](http://www.roscripts.com/Pretty_URLs_-_a_guide_to_URL_rewriting-168.html), or by searching for "htaccess pretty urls" in a search engine.

Comment: Note that this particular method assumes the Apache webserver is being used.

Answer (score 2):

If you are unable to use mod_rewrite (which is the best way), you could use a 404 trap.

That is, normally example.com/2222 would show a 404 page to the user.  Well if you set your server to point to a script of your choice instead of the default 404 page, you can now take the URL example.com/2222 and redirect the user to wherever you want.